# What is the process of storing date and the expiry date?

Tags: node.js, date, mongoose, stripe-payments

Right now I'm facing a huge problem, where when someone made a payment to my system, I have to store the date, both current paying date and expiry date to a MongoDB database using mongoose as its ORM

It is a monthly subscription.

Here's the code

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var PaymentSchema = Schema({

  user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
  firstDuration: Date;
  expiryDuration: Date;


});

// What should I put in the expiryDate?
PaymentSchema.methods.expiryDate = function(firstDuration) {

  this.expiryDuration = "?"
}
```

Let assume that, I'm using moment.js and the user has successfully made a transaction (using stripe), and right now my problem is , how to store both first date and expiry date?

and one more question is, do i need to do a cron job to schedule the payment system?

Comment: if u r already using moment , what's wrong with 
`moment().add(10, 'days').calendar()`

Comment: If you're using Stripe's [subscriptions](https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions), you don't need a cron job as Stripe will automatically create the recurring payments for you.